# Round to 2 Decimal Places Even with Zeros

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, rounding

I am currently using the following logic to round to round to 2 decimal places:

```
billables_all["Parts Charged"] = billables_all["Parts Charged"].fillna(0).round(2)
billables_all["Labor Charged"] = billables_all["Labor Charged"].fillna(0).round(2)
billables_all["Travel Charged"] = billables_all["Travel Charged"].fillna(0).round(2)
billables_all["Invoice Amount"] = billables_all["Invoice Amount"].fillna(0).round(2)
billables_all["USD Amount"] = billables_all["USD Amount"].fillna(0).round(2)
```

However, in the output it appears that it cuts off the 0's.
[image]

Is there a way to have the results output show 0.00 and 397.00?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
billables_all["Parts Charged"] = billables_all["Parts Charged"].apply('{0:.2f}'.format)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, however it turns the values into strings and I still need it to be float. If I turned it back to float afterwards, it dropped the trailing zeros again. But thanks for figuring out the formatting issue.

Answer (score 1):

In a format string you can set the number of decimal places:

```python
billables_all["Parts Charged"] = f'{billables_all["Parts Charged"]:.2f}'
```

Comment: Thanks @linuskmr, however I am getting the following error:
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__

This was my input: 
billables_all["Parts Charged"] = f'{billables_all["Parts Charged"]:.2f}'